# Align or pad some content in these strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these strings:

```
14/04/14     13:31:38     12.54N     88.21W     106.8     3.8ML     Frente al Golfo de Fonseca
14/04/14     11:56:04     11.27N     86.98W     15.2     2.9ML     Frente a Masachapa
14/04/13     11:17:30     12.60N     86.80W     0.2     0.7ML     Cerca del volcan Telica
```

and i want to convert them to this:

```
14/04/14     13:31:38     12.54N     88.21W     106.8     3.8ML     Frente al Golfo de Fonseca
14/04/14     11:56:04     11.27N     86.98W      15.2     2.9ML     Frente a Masachapa
14/04/13     11:17:30     12.60N     86.80W       0.2     0.7ML     Cerca del volcan Telica
```

Want to do it with Regular Expressions in Javascript.

**NOTE 1**: The goal is to align the data in the "*fifth column*", and as you see, the pattern to align is the third appearance of the `.`

**NOTE 2**: Every line is independent (i have each one in an array) I put more than 1 line to show the differents kinds of scenarios, because finally i need to print out all the lines.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: @adeneo I need it, believe me (:

Comment: Looks like tabular data to me. Why not stick it in a table and use CSS to align it?

Comment: @j08691 Could be, but i want it with regx. Sorry (:

Comment: Probably can't be done with just regex.  Regex isn't great at "counting", and you would have to go through and count each section of each line to see what the largest value is for each section and then go back through and add in whitespace to match the count of the largest value. With that said, can you tell us what you are trying to accomplish? If you don't want to put this in a table, what **do** you want?

Comment: @Sam Nope, every line is independent. I put more than 1 line to show the differents kinds of scenarios.

Comment: Then how are we aligning them?  The columns don't seem to change in the first line, the second and third lines seem to change to match up with the first..am I missing something?

Comment: @Sam I updated my question with a note, please look.

Comment: If I get it right, you need to align data on the ``.`` character? Do you HAVE to use regex to achieve this?

Comment: Regex is not the solution..

Comment: @Sam And so, what you propose?

Comment: You can rather easily *locate* your bad spaces: `\dW      ?` but you still need a string operation after that to *insert* the correct number. I think using exclusively RegExes, you need at least two of them.

Comment: @Jongware Yes I think it's possible, but i want an example (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try for each line:

```
line = line.replace(/^((?:\s*\S+){4})\s+?([\s\d]{5}\.)/, "$1    $2");
```

The way is to use a lazy quantifier before a fixed length subpattern that ends with the dot.

Note: works only if the number has one decimal and if the number of digits is between 2 and 6. *(from 0.1 to 99999.9)*

Comment: Yes, always has a decimal format with 1 digit precision.

Comment: **number of significative digits is between 2 and 5** Which digits do you referred?

Comment: @robe007: `106.8` has four digits, `15.2` three, `0.2` two

Comment: Works! but, if the size of the space varies?

Comment: In this case the best way seems to split each lines into fields and add the good number of spaces according to each field size.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really hard way to do this without a single regex, it checks each column to be checked for the string with the longest length, then pads accordingly. It does not account for the period in the numbers in any way, it just adds padding based on length

```
function tabulate(arr, sep, col) {
    var cols = [];

    arr.forEach(function(str) {
        str.split(sep).forEach(function(part, i) {
            Array.isArray(cols[i]) ? cols[i].push(part) : cols[i] = [part];
        });
    });

    cols.forEach(function(arr2, i) {
        if (col.indexOf(i) != -1) {
            var padd = arr2.slice().sort(function(a,b) {
                return a.length - b.length;
            }).pop().length + 1;

            arr2.forEach(function(itm, i2) {
                cols[i][i2] = (new Array(padd - itm.length)).join(' ') + itm;
            });
        }
    });

    return arr.map(function(itm, j) {
        return cols.map(function(itm2) {
            return itm2[j];
        }).join(sep);
    });
}
```

to be used as

```
tabulate( array, separator string, [columns to apply function to (zero based)] )
```

which in this case would equate to something like

```
tabulate(arr, '     ', [4]);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gXzuy/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your time, this works also ! Amazing function, I like it!